# List.Intersect results changing after a foreach

Tags: c#, list, intersect

I have a problem with this piece of code, when I do my intersect method everything works fine.

When I do the count on my intersection before the foreach I have 1.

After the foreach, if do the count again after the foreach I have 0, why is this happening? It should always be 1...

```
var matchedRoles = roles.Intersect(user.Roles);
int before = matchedRoles.Count();

foreach (var matchedRole in matchedRoles)
{
    user.Roles.Remove(matchedRole);
}

int after = matchedRoles.Count();
if (matchedRoles.Any())
{
    accountRepository.Update(user);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because LINQ queries are lazy-evaluated: the result is not produced until it needs to be (which is whenever you call `Count`). It stands to reason that if you modify `user.Roles` in the meantime, the `Count` computed after the modification will be different.

If you want to "fix" the result, then you have to force LINQ to make a local copy of the results, e.g. like this:

```
// Here, ToArray() forces LINQ to immediately produce the results
var matchedRoles = roles.Intersect(user.Roles).ToArray();
```

This way, any further operations on `matchedRoles` will work on a fixed "snapshot" and produce the same results as long as you do not modify `matchedRoles` itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Intersect` uses deferred execution. That means, every time you enumerate the result, the code is executed.

So, your second call to `Count` enumerates the `matchedRoles` enumerable a second time, causing a second execution of `roles.Intersect(user.Roles)`. Because you removed the role from the user, it now returns no items.

To avoid this, enumerate the result once using `ToList` and work with the enumerated values from there:

```
var matchedRoles = roles.Intersect(user.Roles).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq uses deferred execution: it essentially does the intersect twice. Once with the matched role still in user.Roles, and once after your call to remove the role.

Answer (score 0):

your LINQ gets executed again at the moment you access it the second time. If you want to get a copy of the references you could use the ToList method and iterate over its items